# How can I auto-generate years in a calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

So, I'm doing a project which includes having a calendar on it.
So I downloaded a template and I customized it.
The problem is, the calendar only has the year "2017" implemented.
My question is, can I auto-generate the following years?
And if I can, how?

Downhere I'm showing you my code (html and Js)

index.html:

```
<script>
  // fill the month table with column headings
function day_title(day_name) {
    document.write("<div class='c-cal__col'>" + day_name + "</div>");
  }
  // fills the month table with numbers
function fill_table(month, month_length, indexMonth) {
    day = 1;
    // begin the new month table
    document.write("<div class='c-main c-main-" + indexMonth + "'>");
    //document.write("<b>"+month+" "+year+"</b>")

    // column headings
    document.write("<div class='c-cal__row'>");
    day_title("Dom");
    day_title("Seg");
    day_title("Ter");
    day_title("Qua");
    day_title("Qui");
    day_title("Sex");
    day_title("Sab");
    document.write("</div>");

    // pad cells before first day of month
    document.write("<div class='c-cal__row'>");
    for (var i = 1; i < start_day; i++) {
      if (start_day > 7) {
      } else {
        document.write("<div class='c-cal__cel'></div>");
      }
    }

    // fill the first week of days
    for (var i = start_day; i < 8; i++) {
      document.write(
        "<div data-day='2019-" +
          indexMonth +
          "-0" +
          day +
          "'class='c-cal__cel'><p>" +
          day +
          "</p></div>"
      );
      day++;
    }
    document.write("</div>");

    // fill the remaining weeks
    while (day <= month_length) {
      document.write("<div class='c-cal__row'>");
      for (var i = 1; i <= 7 && day <= month_length; i++) {
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 9) {
          document.write(
            "<div data-day='2019-" +
              indexMonth +
              "-0" +
              day +
              "'class='c-cal__cel'><p>" +
              day +
              "</p></div>"
          );
          day++;
        } else {
          document.write(
            "<div data-day='2017-" +
              indexMonth +
              "-" +
              day +
              "' class='c-cal__cel'><p>" +
              day +
              "</p></div>"
          );
          day++;
        }
      }
      document.write("</div>");
      // the first day of the next month
      start_day = i;
    }

    document.write("</div>");
  }
</script>
<br>
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="c-monthyear">
    <div class="c-month">
        <span id="prev" class="prev fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div id="c-paginator">
          <span class="c-paginator__month">JANEIRO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">FEVEREIRO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">MARÇO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">ABRIL</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">MAIO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">JUNHO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">JULHO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">AGOSTO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">SETEMBRO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">OUTUBRO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">NOVEMBRO</span>
          <span class="c-paginator__month">DEZEMBRO</span>
        </div>
        <span id="next" class="next fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <span class="c-paginator__year">2019</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

  <div class="c-calendar">
    <div class="c-calendar__style c-aside">
      <a class=" o-btn " >Anular Senha </a>
      <div class="c-aside__day">
        <span class="c-aside__num"></span> <span class="c-aside__month"></span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="c-cal__container c-calendar__style">
      <script>

      // CAHNGE the below variable to the CURRENT YEAR
      year = 2017;

      // first day of the week of the new year
      today = new Date("Janeiro 1, " + year);
      start_day = today.getDay() + 1;
      fill_table("Janeiro", 31, "01");
      fill_table("Fevereiro", 28, "02");
      fill_table("Março", 31, "03");
      fill_table("Abril", 30, "04");
      fill_table("Maio", 31, "05");
      fill_table("Junho", 30, "06");
      fill_table("Julho", 31, "07");
      fill_table("Agosto", 31, "08");
      fill_table("Setembro", 30, "09");
      fill_table("Outubro", 31, "10");
      fill_table("Novembro", 30, "11");
      fill_table("Dezembro", 31, "12");
      </script>
```

index.js:

```
//global variables
var monthEl = $(".c-main");
var dataCel = $(".c-cal__cel");
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
var monthText = [
  "Janeiro",
  "Fevereiro",
  "Março",
  "Abril",
  "Maio",
  "Junho",
  "Julho",
  "Agosto",
  "Setembro",
  "Outubro",
  "Novembro",
  "Dezembro"
];
var indexMonth = month;
var todayBtn = $(".c-today__btn");
var addBtn = $(".js-event__add");
var saveBtn = $(".js-event__save");
var closeBtn = $(".js-event__close");
var winCreator = $(".js-event__creator");
var inputDate = $(this).data();
today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick solution you don't need to code yourself, you could use something like https://fullcalendar.io/.

Comment: I'm not looking for an event calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create an Array of years based on the current year and the number of years you want in your template.

The following code should cover the basics for what you need, change variables depending on your requirements.

```
let currentYear = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
let startYear = 2016;
let endYearIncrement = 3;
let years = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= currentYear - startYear + endYearIncrement; i++) years.push(startYear + i);
```

The example should generate an array with the following values.

```
[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
```

You could also generate the same array using Javascript's Array built-in function Array.from().

```
let years = Array.from( {length: currentYear - startYear + endYearIncrement + 1}, (v, i) => i + startYear )
```

Again, you can update the code so that you cover the years that you need.